# React: How to do form submit data successfully and then page refresh/redirect to home page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am submitting the data. Api is working fine. **It submits the data if I do not use window.location.href = "/".**
Please update my code that successfully **inserts the data all the time and then page refresh redirects to the home page**. Please help.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
                     const Category_ID = this.props.key_id;
                     const CategoryName = this.state.CategoryName;
               const data = {
                           Category_ID,
                           CategoryName
                     }
                     fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
                           method: 'POST',
                           body: JSON.stringify(data),
                           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                     })
                           .then(response => response.json())
                           .catch(() => console.log("error in posting data"));
                          window.location.href = "/";
              }
       }
```

Thanks

Comment: share how this function is called. You need to create a useEffect to react on data change, useSelector to get data from store and use react router to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Just add the refresh part inside `then()`

```
handleSubmit(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
                 const Category_ID = this.props.key_id;
                 const CategoryName = this.state.CategoryName;
           const data = {
                       Category_ID,
                       CategoryName
                 }
                 fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
                       method: 'POST',
                       body: JSON.stringify(data),
                       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                 })
                       .then(response => {window.location.href = "/";})
                       .catch(() => console.log("error in posting data"));
                      
          }
   }
```